# Castrol ACEA A3/B4 vs ACEA C3

Tags: oil-change

I'm planning to change my engine oil. However I noticed I accidently bought C3 instead of A3/B4 which is currently in the engine. The operating engine is a Corsa C 1.4 from 2002. Could this do any harm? Should I return it in favor of the A3/B4? In the user manual A3/B4 or higher is recommended, but isn't mentioning C3 at all. Thanks!

Comment: Quick google gives this: https://www.castrol.com/en_au/australia/car-engine-oil/engine-oil-viscosity/5w-30.html You should be able to decide...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[C3 fulfills all the A3B4 requirements](https://online.lubrizol.com/relperftool/pc.html), so it should be alright.
Due to the lower SAPS content you could think about replacing the oil earlier.